# Make responsive views in android

Tags: android, user-interface, frontend, responsive

I'm having much trouble with android responsive design. In web design we can use percentage as view size but in android we don't have such thing.
No matter I use ImageButtons or normal Buttons or anything else when I change "device for preview" my hole design will be messy cause the width and height won't change dynamically for example I make everything looks fine on Pixel device but when I change my preview to pixel 2 XL every thing is so small. Bet you don't want to know what happens when I change preview to wear :D

I should mention that I know that I mustn't use hardcoded values and I'm not doing that a lot.
I designed my Buttons with Adobe XD and with that tool I could export my buttons in PNG type and six different sizes (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi ,xxhdpi, xxxhdpi). But even my ImageButtons didn't change their sizes dynamically.
I tried to find solution and I'm sure that there must be a solution but perhaps for my bad English when I search for android responsive design or such things I get some unrelated results.

I really appreciate some help

Here is some example code the ImageButtons sizes won't change dynamically so in small devices like pixel I have the scroll ability but in larger devices like pixel 3 XL the buttons are so small so there is no need to scroll.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:scrollbars="none"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@drawable/all_foods_btn" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                         android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                         android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                         android:contentDescription="@string/main_activity_all_foods_btn_dsc"/>

            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@drawable/profile_btn_main" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                         android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                         android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                         android:contentDescription="@string/main_activity_profile_btn_dsc"/>

        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/classic_decider_btn" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                     android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                     android:contentDescription="@string/main_activity_classic_decider_btn_dsc"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/ssp - try this library: This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Comment: have you defined the dimension files according to screen sizes  ?

Comment: @Krishnasheladiya thank you a lot I used this library and another one named sdp thanks a lot if you post your answer I will flag it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[try this library](http://github.com/intuit/ssp): This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Comment: This library and the equivalent to it with DP both do the app responsive as hell! Surprised I didn't hear of it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `HorizontalScrollView`. That will make it respect the constraints you have set (bottom to parent and top to `button`)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to response but that code was just an example I have responsive problem for almost every view I use. A friend introduced me a library. I'm going to test that out too. And BTW in this code when I change the preview device my ImageButtons won't become larger.

Comment: Great to hear that. Yes, this works if you reduce the screen size but if you want the image to be bigger you will need bigger assets or to scale it (using scaleX and scaleY). Despite that, as long as you make proper use of view constraints you should be fine. Good luck!